# How can I have custom asserts with Shouldly and maintain the call-site-specific assertion messages?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert, xunit, shouldly

I'm using [the excellent `Shouldly` library](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly) in my xUnit tests and I'm finding myself using the set sequence of assertions in different tests, so I'm combining them into new assertion extension methods - but when I do this I lose `Shouldly`'s contextual assertion messages.

Here's my old code, which works with `Shouldly` to include source-level information and call-site context in the `Shouldly` assertion error:

```
[Fact]
public void Dict_should_contain_valid_Foobar_Bar_entry()
{
    IDictionary<String,Bar> dict = ...
    dict.TryGetValue( "Foobar", out Bar bar ).ShouldBeTrue();
    bar.ShouldNotBeNull();
    bar.ChildList.Count.ShouldBe( expected: 3 );
    bar.Message.ShouldBeNull();
}

[Fact]
public void Dict_should_contain_valid_Barbaz_Bar_entry()
{
    IDictionary<String,Bar> dict = ...
    dict.TryGetValue( "Barbaz", out Bar bar ).ShouldBeTrue();
    bar.ShouldNotBeNull();
    bar.ChildList.Count.ShouldBe( expected: 3 );
    bar.Message.ShouldBeNull();
}
```

I converted it to this new extension method in the same project:

```
public static void ShouldBeValidBar( this IDictionary<String,Bar> dict, String barName )
{
    dict.ShouldNotBeNull();
    dict.TryGetValue( barName, out Bar bar ).ShouldBeTrue();
    bar.ShouldNotBeNull();
    bar.ChildList.Count.ShouldBe( expected: 3 );
    bar.Message.ShouldBeNull();
}
```

And so my tests are changed to this:

```
[Fact]
public void Dict_should_contain_valid_Foobar_Bar_entry()
{
    IDictionary<String,Bar> dict = ...
    dict.ShouldBeValidBar( "Foobar" );
}

[Fact]
public void Dict_should_contain_valid_Barbaz_Bar_entry()
{
    IDictionary<String,Bar> dict = ...
    dict.ShouldBeValidBar( "Barbaz" );
}
```

...but now my Shouldly assert messages don't contain any contextual information from `Dict_should_contain_valid_Foobar_Bar_entry` and instead only contains context from `ShouldBeValidBar`.

How can I instruct `Shouldly` to disregard the context of `ShouldBeValidBar` and to use its parent call-site instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Add the `[ShouldlyMethods]` attribute to your custom assert extension method **classes** (not individual extension methods):

```
[ShouldlyMethods] // <-- This, right here!
public static class MyShouldlyAssertions
{
    public static void ShouldBeValidBar( this IDictionary<String,Bar> dict, String barName )
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

### Long version:

After some googling, [and reading articles about how `Shouldly` works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959272/how-does-the-shouldly-assertion-library-know-the-expression-the-assertion-was-ap) - and after reading [the source of Shouldly's secret-sauce: `SourceCodeTextGetter`](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/blob/713c56114d87a53dd7f482a4991a0140cb99721e/src/Shouldly/Internals/SourceCodeTextGetter.cs), I see that it determines which entries in the stack-trace can be overlooked [by the presence of the `[ShouldlyMethods]` attribute](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/blob/ea5739a3859627d4112723c1ddab557d1b842e1b/src/Shouldly/Internals/ShouldlyCoreExtensions.cs) (`Shouldly.ShouldlyMethodsAttribute`) on the method's containing type in each frame of the stack-trace:

```
void ParseStackTrace(StackTrace trace)
{
    [...]

    while (ShouldlyFrame == null || currentFrame.GetMethod().IsShouldlyMethod())
    {
        if (currentFrame.GetMethod().IsShouldlyMethod())
            ShouldlyFrame = currentFrame;

        [...]
    }

    [...]
}
```

```
internal static bool IsShouldlyMethod(this MethodBase method)
{
    if (method.DeclaringType == null)
        return false;

    return
        method
            .DeclaringType
            .GetCustomAttributes( typeof(ShouldlyMethodsAttribute), true )
            .Any()
        ||
        (
            method.DeclaringType.DeclaringType != null
            && 
            method
                .DeclaringType
                .DeclaringType
                .GetCustomAttributes( typeof(ShouldlyMethodsAttribute), true )
                .Any()
        );
}
```

So it's just a matter of adding the `[ShouldlyMethods]` attribute to my extension methods' container classes:

```
[ShouldlyMethods]
public static class ShouldlyAssertionExtensions
{    
    public static void ShouldBeValidBar( this IDictionary<String,Bar> dict, String barName )
    {
        dict.ShouldNotBeNull();
        dict.TryGetValue( barName, out Bar bar ).ShouldBeTrue();
        bar.ShouldNotBeNull();
        bar.ChildList.Count.ShouldBe( expected: 3 );
        bar.Message.ShouldBeNull();
    }
}
```

And now my assert errors have the context of the call-site of `ShouldBeValidBar`. Hurrah!

Comment: Thanks for diving into this! I wasn't able to make it work with `[ShouldlyMethods]` on the extension method itself, but it works when I add the attribute to the containing class.

Comment: @NielsvanderRest That's very weird if it isn't working on your extension methods. Have you done a clean + rebuild of your solution? What does reflection say? Do you have multiple references to different versions of Shouldly?

Comment: I'm on the latest version (3.0.2) which seems to only test for the attribute on `method.DeclaringType`, not the method itself ([source](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/blob/v3.0.2/src/Shouldly/Internals/ShouldlyCoreExtensions.cs)). This would explain the behavior I'm seeing. It appears to do the same as the code you posted.

I was actually triggered to place the attribute on the class, because that's what I saw in Shouldly's source code.

Comment: @NielsvanderRest Oh wow! Good find! I just looked at my own code and saw that I applied `[ShouldlyMethods]` to my extension method class, not the methods. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Just a note: This approach doesn't work if the assertion method is `async`. In this case Shouldly won't be able to obtain the should expression.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski It works for me when the `await` is on the same line, at least.